# Small Box to display where we are hovering in force layout (D3.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I want to see the part where I have zoomed on force layout graph

in short. I want to see the small picture of whole graph in small box which will display where I hovered on the graph with D3.js

Please refer this map Image, I want same thing for force layout.

[image]

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Please check below link
http://jsfiddle.net/dipparmar/466nrbv0/4/

Comment: @DipParmar you need circles to be displayed as well? or simple rect with relative positions will be enough?

Comment: yes I need everything to be displayed in that small area @bumbeishvili

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did this in three steps:

1)Attach a listener for the SVG's mouseover event

```
   var newTx, newTy = 0;
   svg.on("mouseover", function(){
       var coordinates = [0, 0];
       coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
       newTx = (100 - coordinates[0]) ;
       newTy = (100 - coordinates[1]) ;
   });
```

2) Copy the SVG elements at an interval, using the JS cloneNode() function. Use the previously acquired translation to update the new copy of the SVG:

```
   setInterval(function(){
       d3.selectAll("#zoomed-map").select("*").remove();
       var content = document.getElementById("map").cloneNode(true);
       document.getElementById('zoomed-map').appendChild(content);
       if(newTx && newTy ){
                      d3.select("#zoomedmap").select("svg")
                        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + newTx + ',' +  newTy +')');
                }
   },50);
```

3)Update the CSS for the .zoomed-part / #zoomed-map div:

```
#zoomed-map         {
    zoom:120%;
    overflow:hidden;}

#zoomed-map #map   {
     border:none;  }
```

[Here's the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g1amnuu3/5/)

Comment: Thank you :) it's exactly what I needed